# Tax loss - wash sale rule and mutual funds

Tags: united-states, mutual-funds, wash-sale, capital-loss

I was reading up on tax loss harvesting because I recently sold some stock at a loss.  I've know about the wash sale rule, but in my reading [came across this information](https://news.yahoo.com/how-to-make-use-of-tax-loss-harvesting-to-lower-your-tax-bill-161505110.html) (emphesis mine)

> This means the capital gain wouldn’t be canceled out. This reversal, known as the wash-sale rule, can come into effect whether the investor buys the equity back themselves **or a mutual fund purchases the stock without the investor knowing**.

I have shares in several different mutual funds.   It seems possible (but I don't know for sure) that one of those funds may also hold a position in the stock I sold.  Does the above mean that if one of those funds trades that stock I'd loose out on the ability to use the tax loss?  How would that even work if I didn't know they traded the stock?

Comment: JMO but I find it hard to believe that there is correlated tracking between what an investor buys/sells in his personal account and what a mutual fund buys/sells in their portfolio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing that would be

according to IRS Publication 550 [Investment Income and Expenses (Including Capital Gains and Losses)](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p550.pdf)

> A wash sale occurs when you sell or trade stock or securities at a
> loss and within 30 days before or after the sale you:
>
> 1. Buy substantially identical stock or securities,
> 2. Acquire substantially identical stock or securities in a fully taxable trade,
> 3. Acquire a contract or option to buy substantially identical stock or securities, or
> 4. Acquire substantially identical stock for your individual retirement arrangement (IRA) or Roth IRA.

I don't think that a part of a fund such as the S&P 500, and an investment in an individual stock are substantially identical.

Comment: There _are_ wash sale rules for mutual funds/ETFs. Your tax statement from your broker will spell out what was long-term gains, what was short-term gains, and what was a wash sale.